# Substituting text inside buttons with widgets

Tags: python, kivy

My app (using kivy) needs to substitute text with widgets inside an unspecified number of buttons using iteration. I don't use kv language. Only the last button displays any content.

My app should display an unspecified number of buttons. Simplified example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image

        
class Layout(Widget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size=Window.size)
        
        contents = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
        for text in contents:
            button = Button(height=300, size_hint=(1, None))
            
            button.text = text

            self.layout.add_widget(button)
        
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
  

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.form = Layout(self)
        return self.form

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    MyApp().run()
```

Only instead of text buttons display images with descriptions. I change the code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image

        
class Layout(Widget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size=Window.size)
        
        contents = [('img1', 'text1'), ('img2', 'text2'), ('img3', 'text3')]
        for img, text in contents:
            button = Button(height=300, size_hint=(1, None))
            
            button_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, 1))
            label = Label(text=text)
            image = Image(source=f'{img}.jpg', size_hint=(1, 1), allow_stretch=True)
            button_layout.add_widget(image)
            button_layout.add_widget(label)
            button.add_widget(button_layout)
            
            self.layout.add_widget(button)
        
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.form = Layout(self)
        return self.form

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    MyApp().run()
```

And only the last button displays content.

As far as I can understand, at some point Python automatically gets read of the content of the previous button. How can I prevent it? Also what is the best way to center it?
I'm not a native speaker, so sorry for bad grammar. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Button` is not a layout. Is there any specific reason to use it as a container in your second code ?

Comment: @ApuCoder I need to know if it is pressed